# Name for a rule about re-using terminology

Tags: user-behavior, terminology, consistency

Does the rule "Don't use the same name/word to refer to two different things" have a name, and, if so, what is that name?

Comment: The inverse of that rule -- never use different words to describe the same thing -- is [ubiquitous language](http://domaindrivendesign.org/node/132).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't recall a common name for the rule, but I found two definitions of the situation that you're trying to prevent:

In software, when words have several meanings, this is called [overloading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overloaded_expression). Your rule would be 'avoid overloading names/words'.

[Ambiguity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambiguity) is a more general term for the same thing. So the rule could be 'use unambiguous names /words/terms' or 'define your terminology unambiguously'.

Comment: A Google search for "ambigous antonym" led me to **[monosemy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/monosemy)** (via http://www.synonym.com/antonym/ambiguous/)

Comment: Yes, you could go with "avoid polysemy" if you wanted to go concise. :)

Comment: +1, thanks much. _Overloading_ is a great word. So, @PatrickMcElhaney, is _monosemy_.

Comment: Both good terms. I would use _overloading_ for two different concepts having the same reference, and _ambiguity_ when the boundary is uncertain (eg. does "Taxes" include excise, penalties, and fees; or just try asking the Australian Film Commission for their definition of an "Australian film")

Comment: I'd checkmark (accept) this answer or [JohnGB's](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/12269), and chose this one because I happen to like the word _overloading_.

Answer (score 11):

There's no official name, but I like to call it **consistency**.

It describes it and is clear enough that a special name isn't needed.  It also applies to more than just names.

Comment: +1. Nielsen's heuristics say: "Consistency and standards: Users should not have to wonder whether different words, situations, or actions mean the same thing. Follow platform conventions."

Comment: "There is no official name" I am pretty sure that in the other 90% of the english language, which most of us don't know, there is a term for this. My answer below is _"The act of making words mutually exlusive."_

Comment: -1 Since I could __consistently__ use one word to describe different things. This is not about consistency.

Comment: @JeroenEijkhof: Oxford dictionary definition of consistent: (adjective) acting or done in the same way over time, especially so as to be fair or accurate.

Answer (score 6):

There's a precept in [About Face](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470084111) summarized as **"Make things that *are* different *look* different."** This seems like a special case of that.

Comment: So it does. But that doesn't answer my question about a name for the rule. +1, anyway, for the reference.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe **Terminology standardisation**?

In the book [Language, culture and communication in contemporary Europe](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=whacJr2_JVcC&pg=PA21&lpg=PA21&dq=%22terminology%20standardisation%22&source=bl&ots=EOor-T-Z_W&sig=2VKmDN_X6dk4FkpU29LjUm01Tvk&hl=en&ei=q-OJTqmSKYGY1AW2xOgB&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=8&ved=0CEQQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=%22terminology%20standardisation%22&f=false), by Charlotte Hoffmann, she writes:

[image]

Comment: +1, but that seems to be more about setting independent standards of terminology than about one information provider using the same term for two referents.

Answer (score 2):

FWIT, I’ve published a [taxonomy of inconsistencies](http://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2010/07/achieving-and-balancing-consistency-in-user-interface-design.php) to aid in user performance analysis, but I suspect it isn’t widely known.

Inconsistency within different parts of the same product are **internal**, while inconsistency between a product and some other reference (e.g., a standard, a legacy product, or a metaphor) are **external**.

A **contradiction** is when the same thing has two different usages. An **irregularity** is when two different things have the same usage.

The “things” above can be symbols, codes, unit use, formats, terms (like your case), abbreviations, and layout (That makes the mnemonic acronym SCUFTAL).

So what you have is an **internal terminology contradiction**… which, as you probably know, is really bad.

Comment: What about using the same term for both the noun, and the verb action that produces that noun. For example: scheduling a schedule, programming a programme, cooking a cook^W^W^W.

Answer (score 1):

One form of this two-meanings-for-same-term is known as a [synecdoche](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synecdoche), and is particularly confusing.

- Part of something is used to refer to the whole thing (*pars pro toto*), or
- A thing (a "whole") is used to refer to part of it (*totum pro parte*), or
- A specific class of thing is used to refer to a larger, more general class, or
- A general class of thing is used to refer to a smaller, more specific class, or
- A material is used to refer to an object composed of that material, or
- A container is used to refer to its contents.

I was once in a meeting with 6 others discussing a website for a radio station, and only after an hour of confused back and forth did someone stop to ask "when you say 'programme', do you mean the instance of broadcast, or the conceptual ongoing series of broadcasts under that name?".

Comment: Another example I've seen: my username/password settings for my online banking is under the heading Account Settings, which is confusing because my online banking account thus contains accounts (the latter are apparently properly known in banking jargon as "arrangements").

Answer (score 0):

***Mutual exclusivity***,
could be applied to this situation. The act of making words *mutually exlusive*.

*(found no good reference to back me up, anyone?)*

Answer (score -1):

I would reverse that and say "Do use [namespaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace_%28computer_science%29)". Rather than just telling people what not to do, this provides a solution right away.

Comment: Sounds good. But that doesn't answer my question about a _name_ for the rule.

Comment: Well my rule could be named 'namespacing', but you're right, I didn't name your rule. Sorry for trying to help.

Comment: No apology necessary. Thanks for trying. (And I'm not the one who downvoted your answer, FWIW.)